# Maven build with debuging test cases using a tool

Tags: wso2

I want to debug test cases that with maven build. I tried it several ways. But couldn't. Anybody have any experience for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First way

Should comment the below arg line which located in the pom file. You can include this in a parent pom file where you want to debug.

-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

and add below lines and configure the debug configuration.

-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005

Make sure you replace the address 5005 accordingly in debug configuration.

### Second way

you can use -Dmaven.surefire.debug in command line rather using pom arg line which is the easiest way. Then the build commend will be something like this>

$ mvn clean install -Dmaven.surefire.debug